# tsql analytic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

I have fact and date dimension tables. I need to write a query that return for every date member its aggregation function (sum(amount)). But this aggregation function needs to be filtered based on the date.

```
FACT table: InvFactMain
Dim table: Dates
```

Currently I have this query :

```
SELECT D.DATE
       ,(
        SELECT sum(inline.InventoryRetailAmount)
        FROM InvFactMain inline
        WHERE inline.DocumentDate >= DATEADD(day, - @x, D.DATE)
            AND inline.DocumentDate < dateadd(day, - @y, D.DATE)
        ) AS [RetailAmount]
FROM InvFactMain F
     JOIN Dates D ON D.Date_ID = F.DateId
GROUP BY D.DATE
```

I’m sure there is a better and efficient way to implement it.

•   I’m using SQL 2012 , so I can use analytic function as LAG , LEAD, etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please can you give more details about but **this aggregation function need to be filter base on the date that return**

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding what this has to do correctly, I think this should be right...

```
SELECT D.Date, q.s AS [Sum]
FROM Dates D
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT SUM(F.InventoryRetailAmount) s
    FROM InvFactMain F
    WHERE F.Date_ID = D.DateID
          AND D.Date BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -@x, D.Date) AND DATEADD(day, -@y, D.Date)
) q
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this help you?

```
SELECT  D.Date ,
        SUM(inline.InventoryRetailAmount) AS amount
FROM    InvFactMain F
        INNER JOIN Dates D ON D.Date_ID = F.DateId
        INNER JOIN InvFactMain inv ON inv.DocumentDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -@x,
                                                              D.Date)
                                      AND inv.DocumentDate < DATEADD(DAY, -@y,
                                                              D.Date)
GROUP BY D.Date
HAVING  SUM(inline.InventoryRetailAmount) = YOUR_FILTER
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve your goal by using window functions. I've used adventure works for an example.

```
SELECT       d.FullDateAlternateKey
           ,f.SalesAmount
           ,TotalSales = sum(SalesAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY d.FullDateAlternateKey ORDER BY d.FullDateAlternateKey            )
           ,RunningTotalPerDay = sum(SalesAmount) OVER (PARTITION BY d.FullDateAlternateKey ORDER BY d.FullDateAlternateKey ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
           ,RunningTotalLastTenDays = sum(SalesAmount) OVER (ORDER BY d.FullDateAlternateKey ROWS BETWEEN 9 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM           [dbo].[DimDate] d
           JOIN [dbo].[FactInternetSales] f 
           ON d.DateKey = f.OrderDateKey
```

The output of the query:

```
+----------------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+-------------------------+
| FullDateAlternateKey | SalesAmount | TotalSales | RunningTotalPerDay | RunningTotalLastTenDays |
+----------------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+-------------------------+
| 2005-07-01           | 3578.27     | 14477.3382 | 3578.27            | 3578.27                 |
| 2005-07-01           | 3399.99     | 14477.3382 | 6978.26            | 6978.26                 |
| 2005-07-01           | 3399.99     | 14477.3382 | 10378.25           | 6799.98                 |
| 2005-07-01           | 699.0982    | 14477.3382 | 11077.3482         | 4099.0882               |
| 2005-07-01           | 3399.99     | 14477.3382 | 14477.3382         | 4099.0882               |
| 2005-07-02           | 3578.27     | 13931.52   | 3578.27            | 6978.26                 |
| 2005-07-02           | 3578.27     | 13931.52   | 7156.54            | 7156.54                 |
+----------------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers.
I found a very simple way to implement it :
(Just added the filter on the join predicate )

```
select d.date_id,sum(f.InventoryRetailAmount) from InvFactMain f inner join dates d
on f.DocumentDate >  dateadd(day,-@x,d.date)  and f.DocumentDate< dateadd(day,-@y,d.date)
group by d.Date_ID
order by d.Date_ID
```

Works perfect.